# jmh best practices on changing state from benchmarks

Tags: java, microbenchmark, jmh

Consider the jmh-test below.

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
public class Test {
    private int value;

    @Benchmark
    public int testF() {
        return f(value);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int testG() {
        return g(value);
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to benchmark the functions `f` and `g` for a *wide range* of their arguments? `@Param` will work only for a small number of different inputs, `@Setup(Level.Invocation)` may impact the accuracy of results. Other ways (like generating an array of inputs and incrementing the index inside the benchmarks) lead to changing the state from benchmark methods.

```
private int[] values;
private int index;

@Setup
private void generateValues() {
    values = new int[0x10000];
    ...

    index = 0;
}

private int nextValue() {
    return values[index++ & 0xFFFF];
}

@Benchmark
private int testF() {
    return f(nextValue());
}
```

Is it generally a bad idea to change state from benchmark methods?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `OptionsBuilder` which allows you to set the options programmatically via `OptionsBuilder::params(String, String[])`. The options builder is also [demonstrated in the examples](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/5bc528ec6538/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_01_HelloWorld.java).